# graphs and their representation as edge lists

Tags: graph

I have to represent a graph. 
how can this be done using edge lists? what is its format actually?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about adjacency lists . . .

If you have a simple triangle where vertices are labeled `a`, `b`, and `c`, then you would use something like this:

```
a | b, c
b | a, c
c | a, b
```

Depending on the implementation language, you could use, for example, a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the key would be the vertex label and the value would be a list of adjacent vertices.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) as well.